# Excel cannot open .xlsx file created with Spreadsheet::WriteExcel

Tags: perl

I have been using the following script to convert a .csv file to .xlsx format, but Excel says:

> `Cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid, verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the extension matches the format file.`

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use Text::CSV_XS;
open( CSVFILE,">", "C:\\Book1.csv") or die "$!";
my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new("C:\\Book1.xlsx");
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new;

my $row = 0;
while (<CSVFILE>) {
    if ( $csv->parse($_) ) {
        my @Fld = $csv->fields;

        my $col = 0;
        foreach my $token (@Fld) {
            $worksheet->write( $row, $col, $token );
            $col++;
        }
        $row++;
    } else {
        my $err = $csv->error_input;
        print "Text::CSV_XS parse() failed on argument: ", $err, "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module Spreadsheet::WriteExcel only supports the older .xls format; consider upgrading to Excel::Writer::XLSX.

See the notes on CPAN that address this explicitly; http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#Migrating_to_Excel::Writer::XLSX

Answer (score 3):

Use [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Excel%3A%3AWriter%3A%3AXLSX) as a drop-in replacement.

This is actually the suggestion of the `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` documentation which indicates that it has been superseded:  http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#Migrating_to_Excel::Writer::XLSX